# Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 127.0.0.1 IntelliJ Idea

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, intellij-idea, actionscript, socketexception

I am trying to develop a 'Flex Application for Mobile platform' using ActionScript3 on IntelliJ IDEA. The application compiles fine but when I debug the application using an emulator, I get the following error.

ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 127.0.0.1"]

I know that it is something to do with the Sandboxtype and when I debug the application, the sandboxtype is set to "Security.Application". I am not quite sure how to change the sandbox type.

I tried adding "-use-network = true" in the compiler option. But it hasn't changed anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you on? Currently I believe the mobile emulator only works for mac OSX.

Comment: @BennettYeates : Hi Bennett, I am on Windows 7.. The emulator loads fine.. It is only when I try to log in to my application, I get the socket error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had recently updated my AIR SDK from version 3.9 to version 14.0. 
The application stopped throwing "socket error" exception after I changed the project structure to use AIR SDK version 3.9 intead of version 14.0